# What is on this map of the US?

Tags: knowledge, geography

What are the green dots on this map?

HINT: You might want to ignore the two in North Carolina. They aren't very helpful.

[image]

Prior knowledge may help, but anyone can solve this by using easily accessible resources.

Comment: Rot13(Fbzr bs gur ybpngvbaf frrz gb or boivbhf pvgvrf, bguref ner abg ng nyy boivbhf.)

Comment: rot13(Naq juvyr V qvqa'g purpx nyy bs gurz, znal bs gur nernf znexrq ol gur qbgf unir n Jnfuvatgba, rvgure nf n fgerrg anzr be n gbja anzr...)

Comment: @DertereuuiFloireiurtrthr Rot13(V unir orra rkcybevat gung naq bguref, ohg gurl nyfb rkvfg va bgure fgngrf. Lbh zvtug nf jryy fnl cynprf gung fryy zvyx.)

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly... which is why I didn't pursue it as an answer :-)

Comment: I added a hint.

Comment: Is the fact that most of the dots are nearly in a line (as if connected by a highway, railroad, or pipeline) significant, or just a coincidence?

Comment: @dan04 It is significant.

Comment: Not a frequent visitor here so not sure if questions are usually answered but rot13(Qbrf vg unir gb qb jvgu uvtujnl vagrefrpgvbaf?)

Comment: @InBedded16 Yes, it does.

Comment: @InBedded16 You're halfway there. Which ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These dots all represent

> US interstate highway intersections between an East/West highway (even numbered) and a North/South highway (odd numbered) where the two numbers are in the same decade (eg 10 & 17, 8 & 5, 80 & 87)

From left to right,

> these intersections are: 10-15, 8-5, 10-17, 10-19, 30-35W, 30-35E, 44-49, 40-49, 64-69, 64-65, 74-75, 70-71, 70-77, 76-71, 70-77, 76-77, 74-77, 70-79, 76-79, 74-73, 80-81, 86-81, 84-81, 84-87, 90-91, 90-95, 90-93

Two notes:

> Not sure why the two intersections in NC are any less helpful, and does 88 run into 81 right around where 86 does? <s>If so there's a dot missing.</s> Upon looking closer at the map, that dot is in fact there!

Comment: Good job! I suggested ignoring the ones in NC to draw attention to the arrangement from southwest to northeast. The point of this puzzle is to illustrate the relationship between the numbers and the geography. However, I-74 produces some outliers because it has been extended way south of its rightful place in the grid.

Comment: If you click to view a larger image and look closely, you can see that there are two dots very close together in Binghamton, NY: 86-81 and 88-81.

Comment: Some pairs come very close together but one of them terminates before they meet. These include 74-71, 80-87, and 88-87.

Comment: @SamKauffman yep, I did notice some "close but no cigar" intersections. And ah yes I do see the two dots in Binghamton. Good puzzle!

Comment: If currently planned construction projects are completed, we'll get two new dots: 20-27 in west Texas, which will add to the pattern nicely, and 86-87 in New York.

Comment: Also, I should mention that this includes both intersections and concurrencies. I placed a dot in the middle of each concurrency (74-73 was the only long one).

Comment: The complete map is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/highways/comments/12e8pyg/united_states_highway_numbering_grid_visualized/